# Create a connection to sqlite database using Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to create a connection to sqlite database using Python, and I'm not sure why it isn't working. I have already downloaded Sqlite Browser. My code is listed below.

I know once you use `conn=sqlite3.connect("Address.db")`, it should implicitly create a new database if one does not currently exist. However once I save the file, I could not find the corresponding Data Base File.

```
from tkinter import *

from PIL import ImageTk,Image

import sqlite3

root=Tk()

root.title("Hello")

root.geometry("400x400")

conn=sqlite3.connect(path+"Address.db")   #also tried using just ("Address.db")
try:
        c=conn.cursor()

        c.execute('''CREATE TABLE contacts (     
        fName TEXT,
        lName text,
        address text,
        city text,
        state text,
        zipCode integer);''')
        print ('table created successfully')
except:
        print ('error in operation')  
        conn.rollback()

conn.close()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: in your code ‘path’ is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, should give you the SQLite version and path of you working script.

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error
import os

conn = sqlite3.connect("Address.db")
cwd = os.getcwd()
print("pysqlite version", sqlite3.version)
print("sqlite version", sqlite3.sqlite_version)
print("path", cwd)
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using an IDE and your code is running from a different directory to that which you expect.

Try adding this line to print your working directory immediately before you access the database:

```
import os
print(f'Directory: {os.getcwd()}')
```